# How to populate drop down list using Jquery

Tags: php, html, laravel

I m using a javascript method to fetch data from database, which is working correctly and I am getting the data in the alert like this:

**Return Data**

`[{"user_id":3},{"user_id":4}]`

but I want to populate a dropdown with this data.
Can Anyone tell me how to do this in HTML or PHP.

Comment: You want a jquery solution or a PHP solution?

Comment: What do you have so far and are you using a javascript library / framework?

Comment: Great! So you're returning `json`, should be easy enough to parse that and build your drop down list

Answer (score 1):

Inside your ajax success function do

```
var response = $.parseJSON(result); // The result is coming from server

var options = '';

$.each(response, function(i,data){

  options +='<option value="'+ data.user_id +'">' + data.user_id + '</option>';

});

$("#wrapper").append('<select>' + options + '</select>');
```

I assume that there is a wrapper element where you will place the select

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

```
$.ajax({

  url: "ajax.php" // You get the [{"user_id":3},{"user_id":4}] from here

}).done(function(result) {

  var response = $.parseJSON(result); // The result is coming from server

  var options = '';

  $.each(response, function(i,data){

    console.log(data)

    options +='<option value="'+ data.user_id +'">' + data.user_id + '</option>';

  });

  $("#wrapper").append('<select>' + options + '</select>');

});
```

Comment: This Solution is not Working. I am new to Jquery. I think Ajax method will not work

Comment: @CMGOGO That statement directly contradicts what your original post says. You say you are using javascript to get data from a database, which can mean only one thing. Ajax.

Comment: Actually this solution is working. As i said in my first post you just have to place the code in the appropriate function. See update.